# How can I use SQL to create a new table of reorganized data?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I use SQL to transform the following data:

```
 cat    score
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 2     3
 2     5
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
 3     4
```

to create the following subset:

```
 cat score1 score2
 1    2     3
 2    1     3
 3    1     2
```

So that only the first two scores for each value in the column 'cat' will be placed into the transformed table.

Comment: what rdbms (SQL Server, MySQL etc)

Comment: How do we know which score is score1 and which score is score 2?  is the smaller always score 1? or does it matter?

Comment: By first two scores you mean the two lowest?

Comment: I'm using a mySQL database.

Comment: Only the first two scores in each category will be added to the transform.

Comment: For cat 3, only the scores 1 and 2 will be used.

Comment: use select distinct contraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a self join on cat but a.score < b.score so that you get the next minimum value from b.  This doesn't scale well if you need to do n levels deep however.  In that case conditional aggregation on each column with a user variable simulating a row number would likely work better.

This assumes Score1 - X is always that you want to show lowest to highest scores.  We could go highest to lowest as well if needed, or we could use rules to govern which are picked.

DEMO:http://rextester.com/NHDS97935

```
SELECT A.cat, Min(A.score) score1, min(B.Score) score2
FROM SO46102892 A
INNER JOIN SO46102892 B
   on A.cat = B.Cat
  and A.score < B.Score
GROUP BY a.cat;
```

Giving:

```
+----+-----+--------+--------+
|    | cat | score1 | score2 |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   1 |      2 |      3 |
|  2 |   2 |      1 |      3 |
|  3 |   3 |      1 |      2 |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
```

**Alternatively** (as this gives a better n scores scaling approach)

DEMO: http://rextester.com/VLCC24693

Which handles n scores with more grace simply by adding a case statement to the outer select.

In this case we simulate a `row_number () over (partition by cat order by cat, score)` by using two user variables and adjusting their values as needed.

By running this portion alone:

```
SELECT case when cat=@cat then @RN:=@RN+1 else @RN:=1 end RN
     , case when cat=@cat then @cat else @cat:=cat end cat
     , score
FROM (SELECT * FROM SO46102892 ORDER BY cat, score) A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0, @Cat:=0) z
```

You can see how each RN is assigned a 1-x for each category simulating row_number functionality offered in other RDBMS.

```
SELECT cat
     , max(case when RN = 1 then score end) as Score1
     , max(case when RN = 2 then score end) as Score2
     , max(case when RN = 3 then score end) as Score3
     , max(case when RN = 4 then score end) as Score4
     , max(case when RN = 5 then score end) as Score5
FROM (SELECT case when cat=@cat then @RN:=@RN+1 else @RN:=1 end RN
           , case when cat=@cat then @cat else @cat:=cat end cat
           , score
      FROM (SELECT * FROM SO46102892 ORDER BY cat, score) A
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0, @Cat:=0) z
      ) y
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY cat;
```

Giving us:

```
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    | cat | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 | Score5 |
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |   1 |      2 |      3 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
|  2 |   2 |      1 |      3 | 5      | NULL   | NULL   |
|  3 |   3 |      1 |      2 | 3      | 4      | NULL   |
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and we can exclude score 3,4,5 simply by removing it from the outer select.

Comment: @SimonRH Updated to eliminate extra case statement in subqery of alternate answer.